# Exception while converting varbinary to binary array

Tags: c#, sql, filestream

I have a SQL Server table whose `Rawcontent` is of type `varbinary FileStream`

```
TABLE [dbo].[DocTable]
(
    VersionId [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    RawContent [varbinary](max) FILESTREAM  NULL,
```

Now when I am trying to get the fileStream data using :

```
foreach (DataRow dtr in dataTable.Rows)
{
    docStream = (byte[])dtr["RawContent"];
}
```

Getting an exception, can not convert from System.String to System.Byte.

Why I am getting a string back while the content is saved as FileStream on SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

if you have docstream declared as a byte array, you need to use a FileStream object first, and then convert that into a byte array

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716724%28v=vs.100%29.aspx